# How to increase solr Performance

Tags: java, solr

As of now I have 2cr docs to be indexed. Its verified that for each 100 docs its taking around 3 to 4 sec. Based on these statistics its taking huge time . How can boost the performance of Solr. For info each doc having 25-30 fields.

Comment: If I have different cores I have a knowledge of which documents indexed on which core. Is it not possible by a single core

Comment: That's too broad a question for SO really. There's lots of info about this already, Google around. If you've done that stuff and it's still slow then you can come back with a specific use case and what you've tried.

Comment: How are you indexing content? Are you indexing from a single thread? Against a single server? What`s taking time? How often are you committing? Soft commits? Hard commits? What is "2cr" documents?

Comment: Also, provide the code, that you're using for indexing